# How to print tabulated output in Javafx

Tags: javafx-8

Using Javafx and built in print functions how do I print a table with rows and columns ?

I've tryed using String or TableView printing. I've have not been succesfull in styling a TableView to give me a print that is ok. Can not remove background colors and border lines. 
When trying to print strings, using Text and Textflow I can set any tabs on proper positions.

I only want black text on white paper ordered in nice tabbed columns.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? Do you want to print a normal string or do you want to print a `TableView` for example? And is the javafx-2 tag valid? Or solutions using JavaFX8 are also suitable?

Comment: JavaFX8  is valid. String or TableView does not matter. I've have not been succesfull in styling a TableView to give me a print that is ok. Can not remove background colors and border lines. When trying to print strings, using Text and Textflow I can set any tabs on proper positions.

Comment: Have you tried a GridView of TextFlow objects?

Comment: No. You mean that manually create a row/column in the gridView for each row  to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a end comment to this question.
My problem was not being able to style the TableView in a correct manner.

I created a PrintDialog class,, that contains a Stage and Scene. To this I added css style sheet.
This made it possible for me to style the TableView to be printed.

So,, actually my problem was my lack of understanding of JavaFx fundamentals.